# How people measured value of resistance of a conductor and EMF of a battery?

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

When I search on google""how to measure emf of battery "" the answer is to take a conductor of resistance R and multiply it by the current flowing through it!..then I search   ""how is resistance measured """the answer is ohm's law--create a potential difference around a conductor and divide  it by the current flowing!!..ending up again with the same  question how is potential difference  measured ...i m confused ...people who identified  these terms out how did they really caluculated the value?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to measure emf, voltage, current and resistance. In the days before digital multi meters all of these measurement usually done with just one piece of hardware, a moving coil meter. A magnet, a tiny coil and a spring are arranged in such a way as to deflect a pointer in proportion to current flow. You may ask how do you measure emf with a current flow? By using Ohms law. first you construct the coil with many turns to minimize the current draw you then put **a large resistance in series with the coil** to reduce the load on the source of the emf. Often a figure of 20 thousand Ohm's per volt was a practical design criteria, also the coil would be designed to only require 100 micro amperes to deflect full scale and have coil winding resistance of 1 thousand Ohms. With a 119 thousand Ohm resistor in series with the tiny  1000 Ohm coil the meter will be calibrated to display 12 volts when 100 micro amperes flows in the coil.  The same coil can be used to measure current from as little as 1 uA to kA's with suitable low value **resistors in parallel with the coil**. To measure resistance you will need a battery and a combination of resistors. As an exercise you may wish to work out how to measure these parameters with such a tiny coil and a bunch of resistors using Ohm's law. Modern meters use High gain amplifiers resistors and analogue to digital converters to display on modern displays. They are also a vastly more sensitive and draw very little current from what they are measuring.  But Ohm's law is the key to all designs.

Answer (score 1):

Ohmic resistance $R$ of an element is measured indeed by measuring voltage $U$ that occurs on the element when current $I$ flows through it (which is also measured), and then resistance is determined as $U/I$. Result of this determination depends on the current, but for small current we can approximate the reality by useful fiction that there is only one resistance $R$ which is valid for all (small enough) values of current.

So you need to be able to measure 1) current and 2) potential difference. We have devices for both: current is measured by an ammeter (ampermeter) and potential difference is measured by a voltmeter.

Traditional ammeter works by converting electric current to force which is then measured using some other source of force, gravity or spring. Modern ammeters are electronic using solid state components; they do not measure force, but measure effects of the current on the electronic circuits inside.

Then your question boils down to how a voltmeter was constructed so that it can show voltage in volts.

There are different types of voltmeter. Old voltmeters show voltage using a needle and a scale; the needle position is controlled by electric current that the measured voltage source is able to create inside the voltmeter. The voltmeter is carefully set up and calibrated so that the needle shows voltage correctly. What does "correctly" mean? It means the voltage in volts can be determined by human from the position of the needle and setting of the voltmeter. Volt is an international standard of voltage, defined as the potential difference which increases electric potential energy of one Joule per one Coulomb of charge transported from the negative terminal to the positive terminal.

This is accomplished by the process of calibration:
the voltmeter is tuned against stable known voltage reference whose potential difference has known stable value in volts. This reference was originally made from electrochemical cells, but today there are other options based on the Zener diode and the Josephson effect:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_reference